# Routing problems using NodeJS and AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am building my first application using NodeJS & ExpressJS for the backend and AngularJS front end.  I have all my front end routes working how I want, but I cannot figure out how to properly configure the Node backend so that when a specific URL is entered into the address bar, Node renders only the same Angular app every time.

For example, if I use `<a href="/about">About</a>` as a link to my about page in Angular, then the correct view will render and the address bar will show `localhost:8080/about`. However, if I just manually type in `localhost:8080/about` then Node responds with `Cannot GET /about`. Now I understand this is because my backend currently only handles the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var app = express();


app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});

// API
app.get('/api/sync', function(req, res){
    // Here we generate a 32 byte string and make it the key
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var key = crypto.createHash('md5').update(num.toString()).digest('hex');
    key = key.slice(0, key.length/2);

    console.log('Created key: ' + key);
    res.send(key);
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

So what I want to do is make it so EVERY request to Node renders the same `index.html` page but then properly routes the view in Angular based on the URL.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that using:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

And placing this after all other routes I want to catch first will work.

Comment: That's the answer I was gonna give. =) I have a small system done with Angular and Node on GitHub, in case it may be of any help, here's a link: https://github.com/slacktracer/siga
The routes had their own file: https://github.com/slacktracer/siga/blob/master/routes.js

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough reputation yet to just add a comment, it's worth noting that res.render() won't work if you're not using a server-side template rendering engine (as you are using EJS).  You would instead want to use something like res.sendFile() if you were just serving a static HTML and Angular page with all the routing set up in Angular.

```
app.get( '*', function( req, res ) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/public/index.html' );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way handle angular route in angular-app and backend route in backend.

Angular/**Frontend**:

```
 sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'MainController'
   }).
   when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutController'
   }).


   // >>> redirect other routes to
   otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
   });
```

}]);

**Backend:**
For render static html you don't need app.get(...)
simple **place index.html into**:

```
public/index.html
```

and express serve it as html. Other not exists pages(routes) **return 404 error and it is right**.

In this case API fully separate and independent and angular fully single page app. Express  serve static resources needed for angular.